# Are 2B's and 9S's default swords the same?

Tags: nier-automata

When playing through the game as 2B and 9S, you start with their respective default weapons. 2B starts with the Virtuous Contract and 9S starts with the Cruel Oath.

Other than having different descriptions and appearance, both swords seem to be identical. They have had the same stats each time I have upgraded them and it appears it increases both of them have increased attack speeds, as well. Both swords are level 3 in my playthrough with Attack: 420-504, Combo: Lt 6 Hv 3, and ATK Speed Up.

Is there a difference in these swords or is it just lore that distinguishes these 2 swords?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aside from lore and appearance for [Virtuous Contract](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/Virtuous_Contract) and [Cruel Oath](http://nier.wikia.com/wiki/Cruel_Oath), the main difference is the unique ability the weapons receive at lv4

Virtuous Contract receives the Holy Blessing ability where as Cruel Oath receives the Dark Impulse ability

[Weapon Effects](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Weapon+Effects)

> Holy Blessing  Increases attack power when HP is full.
>
> Dark Impulse   Increases attack power when HP is at 30% or less.

As a side note, attack does contain a slight difference at lv3 with different power for heavy

Virtuous Contract

> lv3 - Attack: 420 - 504; Light: 6; Heavy: 3

Cruel Oath

> lv3 - Attack: 420 - 518; Light: 6; Heavy: 2

Comment: I must have misread the numbers for heavy attacks in game, but they were the same up to this point which made me wonder if there was anything special about the swords with numbers being so similar. Good to know and thanks

Comment: Dark impulse gives a 30% attack gain when hp is less then 30% and holy blessing gives a 20% attack increase when hp is full.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Wiki pages for both of these swords shows that the only difference between them is the materials needed to upgrade them.

- [Cruel Oath](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Cruel+Oath)
- [Virtuous Contract](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Virtuous+Contract)

The one exception appears to be at level four, where the Cruel Oath gets the Dark Impulse effect, and Virtuous Contract gets the Holy Blessing effect. Dark Impulse increase attack power when under 30% HP, while Holy Blessing increases attack power at full HP.

As noted in the other answer, at level three for Virtuous Contract, the Heavy combo is +1 higher than Cruel Oath, and the Attack Value has a higher maximum at 518.